# Drawing shapes as textures in LibGDX

Tags: java, android, opengl, libgdx

I'm creating menus in my game specially rectangles with rounded corners and borders. I can do this with a shape renderer but I cannot mix shape renderer and sprite batcher. At the moment my resolution seems to be using large shapes as PNG's and scaling them BUT on a lot of devices this produces blurry corners.

I've read my tutorials on Meshes, shaders, using the shape renderer after the sprite batch (complication layer and performance impact), 9-patch (Border goes blurry, can't do gradients properly)

In android it was fairly simple, we just define the shape in XML and it creates a nice crisp shape example: rounded rect with a border and a gradient.

Could anyone give me some advice as too how I would go about's creating a rounded rect with a gradient, preferably some easy to use implementation that could be used in a reusable class.

Comment: Your current solution of using large PNG shapes would not produce blurry edges if you use filter (MipMapLinearLinear, Linear). Make sure you load the Texture with `useMipMaps` set to true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could draw your shapes to [PixMaps](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html), and then create TextureRegions from them for rendering with SpriteBatch.

The tool-set is a little basic, but you can draw points, lines, triangles, circles, rectangles, fill, or draw areas from another PixMap.

You can draw a rounded rectangle, by drawing two overlapping rectangles and a circle for each corner.

```
PixMap myPixMap = new PixMap(desiredWidth, desiredHeight, pixmapFormat);
myPixMap.setColor(myColor);
myPixMap.fillRectangle(x, y, width, height);

TextureRegion myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(new Texture(myPixMap));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on 9patches. Your usecase should be excactly the same 9patches were made for. So you'll have to make a graphic consisting of 9 regions that can be seperated.

In your case: **4** regions for the 4 corners, **4** regions representing your rect's edges and **1** center region.
Remember, that the edge-regions and the center regions will be stretched depending on the size of the rectangle, that's why you shouldn't use repeating patterns. But horizontal or vertical gradients should work fine.

You can use them with spriteBatch only. There should be no blurry lines, aslong the rounded corners of your graphic will be in a resolution that is good enough.

Here's a link for the libgdx 9patch:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Ninepatches

Here's an image that shows how ninepatches basically work:
http://radleymarx.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/scalable-area.png

Comment: Problem is the borders go different sizes on different resolutions and gradients look weird

Comment: you can define your displayed size by calling yourninepatch.setLeftWidth / setRightWidth/ setTopHeight / setBottomHeight, etc. to maintain the wished size for different resolutions ;). Gradients will only look nice if the gradient begins below the first row and end before the last row. The example image I showed you: http://radleymarx.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/scalable-area.png also contains a gradient. It doesn't look weird at all. Must be something with your graphic. I also used gradients with ninpatches, worked fine for me.