# How to draw a grid using Libgdx and handle click event events for each square

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, game-engine

I want to make a 5x5 grid on an android device screen and handle touch events on each square

How would i go about that ?

This is the code i wrote to render a grid but i couldnt figure out how to handle touch event for each square in the grid

```
    shape.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);

    shape.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    float squareWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/5;
    float squareHeight = squareWidth;

    float padding = squareWidth/10;


    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            shape.box((padding+squareWidth*i),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8+(squareHeight*j)+padding,0,squareWidth-padding,squareHeight-padding,0);
        }

    }


    shape.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is by using a 2d array of [images](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html), and adding the array to a group. This array also gives your grid coordinates for each square.

You can then use hit detection to tell which square was hit.

This method has many benefits, they are actors so, can individually become not touchable if desired. In the same way they can become invisible, simply by changing the setVisible. As they are in a group these options can be toggled for every one at the same time, useful for when switching screens, without a for loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so how i draw a geometry /square using image ? i dont want to provide an asset for sqaure , should be drawn as a geometry . And before i forget , thanks for answering this

Comment: You can draw it as a pixmap, then get the texture from the pixmap. See this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922539/drawing-shapes-as-textures-in-libgdx).